# How can I load OpenVDB files with correct scaling and translation

Tags: transforms, import, volumetrics

Dear Blender community,

I have been trying to use Blender to visualize molecules and volumetric data from molecular dynamics simulation. I managed to save my data in OpenVDB format using the pyopenvdb library as described in https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/python.html, and I am very happy with the visualization.

However, I did not manage to load the object with the appropriate scaling and position. This is important because I want to exactly overlay the volume with other objects, such as molecules imported using Atomic Blender. So far, I tried setting the `'center'` and `'scale'` attributes in pyopenvdb as follows:

```
vdb_grid = vdb.FloatGrid()
vdb_grid.name = "density"
vdb_grid.copyFromArray(data, tolerance=0.1)
vdb_grid['center'] = [-20, -20, -20]
vdb_grid['scale'] = 0.5

vdb.write("out.vdb", grids=[vdb_grid])
```

However, it seems that the information is not used by Blender. The volume is still loaded at full size and at the cursor position. My current workaround is to add some density at the grid corners to give the volume object a well-defined size, and then manually set the translation and scaling properties in Blender. The extra density is needed because the density does not always fill the whole grid, and If the grid is trimmed, I don't know where exactly Blender puts the object's center relative to my grid coordinates.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that, or are there other OpenVDB attributes that I could use? I would like to position my volumes *exactly*, based on my original data, and I would prefer a method which requires as little manual copying of numbers as possible. I would also prefer not to use my current workaround, where I add fake density to fix the size of the object.